# SQL ISNULL CASE

Tags: sql-server, case, isnull

Can someone please explain to me in laymen terms why do we put ISNULL? I have an understanding of IS NULL but can't seem to put it together in this CASE context and what would be the impact if you didn't put it.

UpdateTime refers to when a particular row has been updated with new information

Example 1:

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(DB1.UpdateTime,'') >= ISNULL(DB2.UpdateTime,'') THEN ISNULL(DB1.UpdateTime,'')
            ELSE DB2.UpdateTime
        END AS UpdateTime
FROM dbo.DB1_Result DB1 INNER JOIN dbo.DB2 DB2
ON DB1.ID = DB2.ID
```

Example 2:

StartTime = 01/01/2022

```
WHERE
  (ISNULL(DB1.UpdateTime,'') >= @StartTime
```

Thank you!

Comment: What data type is UpdateTime? `01/01/2022` is not a time it's a *date*; what is your RDBMS?

Comment: Hi, this is more of an example. The datatype in production would be DATETIME. I'm using SSMS

Comment: Is this your query or code you've inherited? Have you experimented with removing the `isnull` and adding in the result of the expression in the `select`?

Comment: This `ISNULL(DB1.UpdateTime,'')` is bad, you need to ensure that the second parameter is a valid value matching the type of the first parameter.

Comment: The short answer is that ANSI SQL says that you can't directly compare nulls to other values. `NULL >= NULL` would never be true.

Comment: You should look to replace this sort of thing with the [`GREATEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) function eventually though not viable at the moment unless you only use Azure SQL Database.

Comment: `ISNULL(DB1.UpdateTime,'')` You really need to understand implicit datatype conversion and [datatype precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). The engine cannot compare values of different types so one will be converted based on the precedence rules. An empty string will be converted to date (or datetime) of Jan 1 1900 - which is unfortunate IMO.

Answer (score 1):

SQL uses [trinary logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic): true, false, and null. null means the value is *unknown*, it could be anything.

If you try to compare anything with null you get null, even null. `null = anything` is null. `null <> anything` is null. `null < anything` is null. `null > anything` is also `null`.

Null is neither equal nor not equal to itself. `null = null` is null and `null <> null` is null. This is why we write `x is null` not `x = null`.

If you were to write

```
case
when DB1.UpdateTime >= DB2.UpdateTime then
  db1.UpdateTime
else
  db2.UpdateTime
end
```

and if either one is null the `DB1.UpdateTime >= DB2.UpdateTime` will be null. Case will treat that as false and return `DB2.UpdateTime`. If either value is null, you always get `DB2.UpdateTime` even if it's null and `DB1.UpdateTime` is not.

They don't want that. If `DB2.UpdateTime` is null, they want to return `DB1.UpdateTime`. If `DB1.UpdateTime` is null, they want to return `DB2.UpdateTime`. So they've used `isnull` to convert null to something that will compare as less than any time; `''` works for that.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c16cab69e69d42ef0afb974d5bda99e1).

Note: `ELSE DB2.UpdateTime` may want to be `ELSE isnull(DB2.UpdateTime, '')` to be consistent with `THEN ISNULL(DB1.UpdateTime,'')`.

Note: isnull is a SQL Server extension. The SQL standard is coalesce.

Note: `''` is not a timestamp. It happens to work, but other SQL servers will reject it. `1900-01-01` would be better.